# Multiple GameObjects Instantiated Between Two Angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn ***n*** GameObjects between angles equally spaced out.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to adjust the "cone" to so that the enemy can shoot in any direction, in any density.

**Can someone see what I have done wrong?**

[image]

These are enemy projectiles. That I am trying "scatter shot". Think of the dragon from Level 1 in NES Zelda:

[image]

Though, I am not entirely sure what is happening with my implementation.

[image]

**Projectile.cs**

```
    public Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;
    public float moveSpeed = 4.0f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _body.MovePosition(transform.position + (new Vector3(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y, 0).normalized) * (moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
```

**MultiShooter.cs**

```
public GameObject projectileObject;
public Transform projectileEmitter;
[Range(2, 10)] public int numToShoot = 3;
[Space]
[Range(0, 360)] public int angle = 30;
[Range(1, 50)]  public float rayRange = 10.0f;
[Range(0, 360)] public float coneDirection = 180;
public void OnStartShooting()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= numToShoot; i++)
    {
        var projectile = Instantiate(projectileObject);
        projectile.transform.position = projectileEmitter.position;
        var projectileScript = projectile.GetComponent<Projectile>();
        projectileScript.moveDirection = DirFromAngle(((angle / i) + coneDirection)* pointDistance, rayRange);
        projectile.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public Vector3 DirFromAngle(float angleInDegrees, float range)
{
   return Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleInDegrees, Vector3.forward) * transform.up * range;
}
```

**Editor script to show the lines.**

```
private void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        MultiShooter fow = (MultiShooter)target;
        Handles.color = Color.magenta;

        Vector3 upDirection = fow.DirFromAngle((-fow.angle / 2.0f) + fow.coneDirection, fow.rayRange);
        Vector3 dwDirection = fow.DirFromAngle((fow.angle / 2.0f) + fow.coneDirection, fow.rayRange);

        Handles.DrawLine(fow.projectileEmitter.position, upDirection);
        Handles.DrawLine(fow.projectileEmitter.position, dwDirection);

    }
```

Comment: What happens using the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `i`th object, the fraction of angular distance from one side of the range to the other can be expressed with the formula i/(numToShoot-1) for values ofnumToShoot > 1. If numToShoot == 1, you can just have the percentage be 50% to shoot right in the middle of the range.

Your drawing method seems to work with coneDirection ± angle/2, so we can subtract .5 from this angular percentage to express it in terms of angular distance from the center of the range.

Then we can use the same math as the drawing method with coneDirection + angle percentage * angle range:

```
public void OnStartShooting()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numToShoot; i++)
    {
        var projectile = Instantiate(projectileObject);
        projectile.transform.position = projectileEmitter.position;
        var projectileScript = projectile.GetComponent<Projectile>();
        float anglePercentage;
        if (numToShoot == 1)
            anglePercentage = 0f;
        else
            anglePercentage = (float)i/(numToShoot-1f) - .5f;

        projectileScript.moveDirection = DirFromAngle(
                  coneDirection 
                + anglePercentage * angle, rayRange);
        projectile.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```